# Can't import patterns in django

Tags: python, django

i am defining urls in django url.py file. whenever i put urls in browser and run that it says :

```
cannot import name patterns
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/
Django Version: 1.2.4
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
cannot import name patterns
Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\registration\backends\default\urls.py in <module>, line 20
Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.1
Python Path:    ['C:\\Users\\Tameen\\lmn', 'C:\\Python27\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Python27', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\PIL']
Server time:    Thu, 20 Mar 2014 17:17:58 +0500
```

**My Url.py file is:**

```
    from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

 Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    (r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^pastebin/', include('pastebin.urls')),
    (r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    # Example:
     (r'^lmn/', include('lmn.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
     (r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
     #(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    )
```

Comment: Pretty old version of django. Can't you update it before fixing the import issue?

Comment: i downloaded it today. its new version.

Comment: how about importing `from django.conf.urls import patterns, url` ? truth be told the django version is quite old, so it makes it difficult for me to check it on my environment

Comment: from where i can install the new one?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/install/#install-the-django-code

Comment: after installing new version of django it says django.core.management can't import execute_manager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the newest version of `django-registration` (1.0) with a (very) old version of `django` (1.2). `django-registration` uses [the following code](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/8f242e35ef7c004e035e54b4bb093c32bf77c29f/registration/backends/default/urls.py?at=default#cl-20) in it's `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns
```

With your version of django, it needs to be

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns
```

You have two options:

1. [Upgrade your version of Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/install/). If you are using `pip` you can do: `pip install django==1.6`.
2. Downgrade your version of `django-registration`. If you are using `pip`, you can do `pip install django-registration==0.8` (or maybe to 0.7)

obviously the first option is preferred as 1.2 is a very old django version

Comment: after installing new version of django it says django.core.management can't import execute_manager

Comment: `execute_manager` was removed from Django. Please create a new `manage.py` to reflect the changes in the API.

Comment: thank you for quick response can i reply you later as there are some electricity problem

Comment: it's saying: 'no module registeration'

Comment: These are all separate issues. You probably haven't set up your `settings.py` correctly, or reinstalled `django-registration`.

Comment: can i paste my setting.py file here/ please @TimmyO'Mahony

Comment: No, you need to go through the [installation guide for django 1.6](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/install/) as well as the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/) and make sure all your settings and folders are set up correctly. If there's still a problem, open a new question with the details.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is not in your `urls.py` but in the `registration` application module which, presumably, is not Django 1.2.X compatible.

The last version is [1.6.2](https://www.djangoproject.com/download/)

Comment: it's saying: 'no module registeration'

Comment: Did you "pip install" it as @Timmy said? Did you add it to you `INSTALLED_APPS` list?

Comment: I think it's better if you run through the first django tutorial, or you won't be able to go ahead by yourself: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/

Answer (score 0):

Django new versions(1.8 and above) are not compatible with

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns
```

and

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),)
```

structure. Use this instead of it.In your myapp directory > views.py include the view you want to get.. ex:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.http import HttpResponse

def hello(request):
    text = """<h1>welcome to my app !</h1>"""
    return HttpResponse(text)
```

then in your urls.py include following code.

```
from django.conf.urls import   url , include
from django.contrib import admin
from myapp.views import hello
admin.autodiscover()


urlpatterns =[

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^hello/',hello),
]
```

Then you should be able to render the hello view properly. :)